# No result on multiple join with PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When I try this code:

```
$this->db->select('customers.customerid, customers.firstname');
$this->db->from('customers');

$this->db->join('orders', 'orders.customerid = customers.customerid');
$this->db->join('order_domains', 'order_domains.orderid = orders.orderid');
$this->db->join('order_hostings', 'order_hostings.orderid = orders.orderid');
$this->db->join('order_servers', 'order_servers.orderid = orders.orderid');


$this->db->group_by('orders.customerid');
$query = $this->db->get();

$domainusers = $query->result();
var_dump($domainusers);
```

I've tried using inner joins but still everything I try will return a empty result:

```
var_dump(); ---> array(0) { }
```

When I comment out two of the last 3 joins:

```
//$this->db->join('order_hostings', 'order_hostings.orderid = orders.orderid');
//$this->db->join('order_servers', 'order_servers.orderid = orders.orderid');
```

It will return results:

```
var_dump(); ---> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#17 (1) { ["customerid"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

I am using codeigniter for this project, does anyone have any idea why it returns empty results once I use multiple joins?

Comment: Logically it is happening because there is no matching records on either or both of order_hostings or order_servers.

Comment: There are no reasons why this should happen other that what Kickstart commented about. I personally have done this lots of times with more than 4 joins and only encountered problems when data doesn't correctly exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following in multiple blocks:

```
$this->db->distinct('orders.customerid');
$this->db->from('orders');

$this->db->join('order_domains', 'orders.orderid = order_domains.orderid', 'inner');
$this->db->join('customers', 'customers.customerid = orders.customerid');

$this->db->group_by('orders.customerid');
$query = $this->db->get();

$domainusers = $query->result();
var_dump($domainusers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run `$this->db->last_query();` to view the actual query that ran. It's often handy to run it in a MySQL client and play around with the query to figure out what's going on.

You can also often use EXPLAIN in MySQL to get some clues:

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT customers.customerid, customers.firstname
 FROM customers
 LEFT JOIN...
```

etc...

Comment: SELECT `customers`.`customerid`
FROM (`customers`)
INNER JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`customerid` = `customers`.`customerid`
INNER JOIN `order_hostings` ON `order_hostings`.`orderid` = `orders`.`orderid`
GROUP BY `orders`.`customerid`    ---------    this is whet the query looks like

Comment: What output do you get from:

`EXPLAIN SELECT customers.customerid FROM (customers) INNER JOIN orders ON orders.customerid = customers.customerid INNER JOIN order_hostings ON order_hostings.orderid = orders.orderid GROUP BY orders.customerid`

Comment: I made a picture of it since in php it isn't very readable ---->   http://snag.gy/w3GgO.jpg

Comment: As @Kickstart said, it looks like you just haven't got any data which is returned by that query? Post an example result which you expect *should* come up.. so just show a record in the customers table, which also has an order, which is then linked to order_hostings.

Comment: the problem is if I remove the domain and server join and leave the hosting join on it returns 3 results, same for domain only it returns 1 result, I  want all 4 of them

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$this->db->select('customers.customerid, customers.firstname');
```

To

```
$this->db->select('customers.*, orders.*, order_domains.*, order_hostings.*, order_servers.*');
```

If after that you get some results, keep only needed fields from EACH joined table in select statement.

Comment: this results in "unknown table order_domains"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing those two to LEFT OUTER JOINs. This way if there is no matching record on those tables it will not prevent the row being returned (just fields from those tables will be set to NULL in that case).

Not really sure with codeigniter but think it is done something like this:-

```
$this->db->select('customers.customerid, customers.firstname');
$this->db->from('customers');

$this->db->join('orders', 'orders.customerid = customers.customerid');
$this->db->join('order_domains', 'order_domains.orderid = orders.orderid');
$this->db->join('order_hostings', 'order_hostings.orderid = orders.orderid', 'left');
$this->db->join('order_servers', 'order_servers.orderid = orders.orderid', 'left');


$this->db->group_by('orders.customerid');
```